# Python binding for C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, python, reference, python-sip

I have a class similar to the following:

```
class A {
    vector<double> v;
    double& x(int i) { return v[2*i]; }
    double& y(int i) { return v[2*i+1]; }
    double x(int i) const { return v[2*i]; }
    double y(int i) const { return v[2*i+1]; }
}
```

I want to have the following Python code work:

```
a = A()
a.x[0] = 4
print a.x[0]
```

I was thinking of `__setattr__` and `__getattr__`, but not sure if it works. An alternative is to implement the following Python:

```
a = A()
a['x', 0] = 4
print a['x', 0]
```

not as good as the previous one, but might be easier to implement (with `__slice__` ?).

PS. I am using sip to do the binding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible with `__getattr__` and custom `%MethodCode`; however, there are a few points to take into consideration:

- An intermediate type/object needs to be created, as `a.x` will return an object that provides `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.  Both methods should raise an `IndexError` when out of bounds occurs, as this is part of the old protocol used to iterate via `__getitem__`; without it, a crash would occur when iterating over `a.x`.
- In order to guarantee the lifetime of the vector, the `a.x` object needs to maintain a reference to the object that owns the  vector (`a`).  Consider the following code:

  ```
  a = A()
  x = a.x
  a = None # If 'x' has a reference to 'a.v' and not 'a', then it may have a
           # dangling reference, as 'a' is refcounted by python, and 'a.v' is
           # not refcounted.
  ```
- Writing `%MethodCode` can be difficult, especially when having to manage the reference counting during error cases.  It requires an understanding of the python C API and SIP.

For an alternative solution, consider:

- Design the python bindings to provide functionality.
- Design class(es) in python to provide the pythonic interface that uses the bindings.

While the approach has a few drawbacks, such as the code is separated into more files that may need to be distributed with the library, it does provide some major benefits:

- It is much easier to implement a pythonic interface in python than in C or the interoperability library's interface.
- Support for slicing, iterators, etc. can be more naturally implemented in python, instead of having to manage it through the C API.
- Can leverage python's garbage collector to manage the lifetime of the underlying memory.
- The pythonic interface is decoupled from whatever implementation is being used to provide interoperability between python and C++.  With a flatter and simpler binding interface, changing between implementations, such as Boost.Python and SIP, is much easier.

---

Here is an walk-through demonstrating this approach.  First, we start with the basic `A` class.  In this example, I have provided a constructor that will set some initial data.

`a.hpp`:

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include <vector>

class A
{
  std::vector< double > v;
public:
  A() { for ( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) v.push_back( i ); }
  double& x( int i )         { return v[2*i];       }
  double  x( int i ) const   { return v[2*i];       }
  double& y( int i )         { return v[2*i+1];     }
  double  y( int i ) const   { return v[2*i+1];     }
  std::size_t size() const   { return v.size() / 2; }
};

#endif  // A_HPP
```

Before doing the bindings, lets examine the `A` interface.  While it is an easy interface to use in C++, it has some difficulties in python:

- Python does not support overloaded methods, and idioms to support overloading will fail when the argument type/counts are the same.
- The concept of a reference to a double (float in Python) is different between the two languages.  In Python, the float is an immutable type, so its value cannot be changed.  For example, in Python the statement `n = a.x[0]` binds `n` to reference the  `float` object returned from `a.x[0]`.  The assignment `n = 4` rebinds `n` to reference the `int(4)` object; it does not set `a.x[0]` to `4`.
- `__len__` expects `int`, not `std::size_t`.

Lets create a basic intermediate class that will help simplify the bindings.

`pya.hpp`:

```
#ifndef PYA_HPP
#define PYA_HPP

#include "a.hpp"

struct PyA: A
{
  double get_x( int i )           { return x( i ); }
  void   set_x( int i, double v ) { x( i ) = v;    }
  double get_y( int i )           { return y( i ); }
  void   set_y( int i, double v ) { y( i ) = v;    }
  int    length()                 { return size(); }
};

#endif // PYA_HPP
```

Great!  `PyA` now provides member functions that do not return references, and length is returned as an `int`.  It is not the best of interfaces, the bindings are being designed to provide the needed *functionality*, rather than the desired *interface*.

Now, lets write some simple bindings that will create class `A` in the `cexample` module.

Here is the bindings in SIP:

```
%Module cexample

class PyA /PyName=A/
{
%TypeHeaderCode
#include "pya.hpp"
%End
public:
  double get_x( int );
  void set_x( int, double );
  double get_y( int );
  void set_y( int, double );
  int __len__();
  %MethodCode
    sipRes = sipCpp->length();
  %End
};
```

Or if you prefer Boost.Python:

```
#include "pya.hpp"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cexample)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_< PyA >( "A" )
    .def( "get_x",   &PyA::get_x  )
    .def( "set_x",   &PyA::set_x  )
    .def( "get_y",   &PyA::get_y  )
    .def( "set_y",   &PyA::set_y  )
    .def( "__len__", &PyA::length )
    ;
}
```

Due to the `PyA` intermediate class, both of the bindings are fairly simple.  Additionally, this approach requires less SIP and Python C API knowledge, as it requires less code within `%MethodCode` blocks.

Finally, create `example.py` that will provide the desired pythonic interface:

```
class A:
    class __Helper:
        def __init__( self, data, getter, setter ):
            self.__data   = data
            self.__getter = getter
            self.__setter = setter

        def __getitem__( self, index ):
            if len( self ) <= index:
                raise IndexError( "index out of range" )
            return self.__getter( index )

        def __setitem__( self, index, value ):
            if len( self ) <= index:
                raise IndexError( "index out of range" )
            self.__setter( index, value )

        def __len__( self ):
            return len( self.__data )

    def __init__( self ):
        import cexample
        a = cexample.A()
        self.x = A.__Helper( a, a.get_x, a.set_x )
        self.y = A.__Helper( a, a.get_y, a.set_y )
```

In the end, the bindings provide the *functionality* we need, and python creates the *interface* we want.  It is possible to have the bindings provide the interface; however, this can require a rich understanding of the differences between the two languages and the binding implementation.

```
>>> from example import A
>>> a = A()
>>> for x in a.x:
...   print x
... 
0.0
2.0
4.0
>>> a.x[0] = 4
>>> for x in a.x:
...   print x
... 
4.0
2.0
4.0
>>> x = a.x
>>> a = None
>>> print x[0]
4.0
```