# use c++ array in python

Tags: python, c++, blender

I created a array in C++. I want to use the values of the array in a python code.(more specifically I want to use it in blender).

I surfed the web but could not get much information.

Is doing this possible? What are the ways of doing it?

Comment: maybe duplicated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882089/wrapping-arrays-in-boost-python

Comment: You can use boost-python to achieve that. It is basically a library for writing your python modules with C++. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/python/doc/index.html